# How to prevent a key to be inserted in an EditText if it comes from a specific keyboard

Tags: android, barcode-scanner

i'm working with a bluetooth barcode scanner acting like a bluetooth keyboard, i want to handle the keys when my user scan something but i know he can focus any EditText in the activity so i want to detect which keyboard he uses in my KeyEvent like this :

```
if KeyEvent.getDevice().getName().equals("Datalogic Scanner") //do stuff
else //let the edittext add the letter
```

and prevent the EditText to be edited and instead store and process the values the scanner send.

I tried returning true in dispatchKeyEvent in my activity,
I tried returning true in onKeyDown in my activity,
I tried returning true in a OnKeyListener on my EditText and overriding OnKeyDown on my EditText class, but nothing works, the text still get inserted in my EditText.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the [dispatchKeyEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#dispatchKeyEvent%28android.view.KeyEvent%29) like that :

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    return scanManager.handleDispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

And in the scanManager class, you should do something like that :

```
public boolean handleDispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
// handle the event
return true;
}
```